# How to refuse connection to Go and wifidirect?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I create a game with multiplayer option. For example, I need 4 players. Once I found the 4 players I found out that any other player can still ask for a connexion with the GO.

So is there a way to either

- stop advertising the device
- do not show the connexion invitation message on GO deceive

WifiDirect works nice but at least there is no means for avoiding connexion. Anyone can ask for a connection as long as the device is advertised. They must be a way to say that it is no longer accessible. But for that, we need to remove the Group and stop the Access Point. So the player loses connexion.

Strange behavior!

Answer (score 0):

I have found some other strange behavior.

If after the CreateGroup on device1 i change the WifiDirect name. I found out that other device3 scanning for direct wifi still see the old name of the GO device.

If i am already connected with with device2 and that i do not remove the OG and keep the server (UDP connexion) running on device1. If i restart the OG device1 i get a new OG name and Device2 can reconnect on the UDP server of Device1. Wich is always 192.168.49.1.

It i quite strange the WifiDirect protocole !

Answer (score 0):

So i try to forget to use wifidirect and go back to normal wifi hotspot to establish connection after the use of wifi direct to send password connexion and i found out that you cannot anymore scan the wifi hotspot using android 6 because you need to allow GPS location to get the scan result.

What append with android ?

The funny things is that when i scan the wifi hotspot using my device i do not need to set the location ON. Why it is necessary in programming ?

Answer (score 0):

So i find another solution to get ride off wifi direct annoying probleme.
As p2pService work the same.

Domage qu'android ne fasse que le travail a moitié.

regards.

PS: you can delete this post if you like. Aniway it look like there is no answer.